# Harbor Helm Chart: Issue with Disabling Redis & lightweight helm package by keep only minimal services

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

I've been working on deploying Harbor using the goharbor/harbor-helm Helm chart. My goal is to streamline the Harbor deployment by cutting down some of the services, specifically leaving only Core, Registry, Postgres, and Portal services.

However, I've encountered an issue with the Core service. I've disabled Redis connection for the Core service in the configmap.yaml file as follows:
cache:
redis:
enabled: false

Despite this, the Core service pod trying to make connection to redis to start, and I'm seeing the following error:
[FATAL] [/core/main.go:153]: failed to initialize cache: retry timeout: dial tcp: lookup release-name-harbor ││ -redis on 10.43.0.10:53: no such host.

I'm seeking guidance from the community on resolving this issue. Here are some details about my setup:
Kubernetes Platform: RKE2 v1.28.6
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Additionally, I'm interested in understanding if it's feasible to run Core and Registry services independently. Are there any concerns or requirements I should be aware of when attempting this? My Ultimate goal to make a lightweight helm package by keep only minimal services

Any help, suggestions, or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

it should be like running minimal service for more lightweight helm chart for kubernetes cluster.

Comment: check values.yaml as a value there might override the config you made in confiMap.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Harbor needs Redis, it is using it for jobservices jobs and caching. Theoretically, it can run without Redis, but codewise it is a hard dependency.

You could run Harbor without the job service, but you would miss some core functionalities of harbor:

```
AUDIT_LOGS_GDPR_COMPLIANT
EXECUTION_SWEEP
GARBAGE_COLLECTION
IMAGE_SCAN
P2P_PREHEAT
PURGE_AUDIT_LOG
REPLICATION
RETENTION
SCAN_DATA_EXPORT
SCHEDULER
SLACK
SYSTEM_ARTIFACT_CLEANUP
WEBHOOK
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for information ,
One doubt, From the default helm chart what are the service can be cut down .
Below are the helm chart template .

Comment: Hi Thanks for information ,
One doubt, From the default helm chart what are the service can be cut down .
Below are the helm chart templates . 
core,  exporter,  ingress , internal,  jobservice,  metrics,  nginx,  portal , registry,  trivy

Comment: ingress, core, registry are essential.